# Inherit commands from another program

Tags: windows

I'm trying to skip a game launcher. The first program Arc.exe starts a patcher.exe. The patcher starts a launcher.exe. The launcher starts the game elementclient.exe.

Every time patcher opens, it verifies the game version and it take a while.
I could run the patcher manually after maintenance, opening it every time is not necessary.
I can't open the game directly because it requires a command line containing a token that changes every time I login to Arc.exe.

So, my idea was to make a fake "patcher.exe" that just opens the game with the random token.

I tried the AutoHotKey script.

> RunWait, C:\Program Files (x86)\PWI_en\element\elementclient.exe startbypatcher, C:\Program Files (x86)\PWI_en\element.

but it doesn't not pass on the Arc gives.

Here is what Arc.exe uses as command line to start the patcher.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\PWI_en\patcher\patcher.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\PWI_en\launcher\launcher.exe" user:john2000 token:Q6Ua6jgYpsSThi2J coreclient:1 arc:1 locale:en /update.

I need my patcher to run the elementclient.exe with those paramenters.

> user:john2000 token:Q6Ua6jgYpsSThi2J coreclient:1 arc:1 locale:en /update.

If wasn't for that token I could do it.